# I am trying to maximize the following function

Tags: maximize

```
Maximize[{ (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]] )*
   Log[(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]] )], 
  x > 0 && y > 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

This returns the same function as output. I have no idea why. Sorry if it is too basic. I am very new to mathematica.